# Automatically add where clause to every queries on a model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Currently I am to do `Model::where('status', 1)` to filter off inactive models before adding any other subqueries to it. I find myself doing this all the time and Its quite stressful as sometimes I could forget to add that part. I wish to have something that will automatically add the where clause anytime I run a query on the model. Something that works like the typical Laravel SoftDeletes that adds the `WHERE deleted_at IS NULL` clause automatically to all queries.

Example:

Instead of writing `Model::where('status', 1)->first()`, I could just write `Model::first()` and this will be automatically transformed to `Model::where('status', 1)->first()`.

How do I achieve this please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking are the
[Query Scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#query-scopes)